# When getLastModified is called?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am reading a book and came to this point HttpServlet.getLastModified with an example in the below. But the thing confused me is: When actually this method get called? Is it always implicitly get called even though we don't write it to create a cache update? or We have to write it to update the cache? Another question is if I get a respond about that the file was not modified then how can I get that information?

Another scenario is whether I keep getLastModified  or not in the code I do not see any difference. Is there a way to get notified?

```
public class GetLastModified extends HttpServlet {

 private long modTime;
 private int[] numbers = new int[5];

 public void init() throws ServletException {

      modTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 * 1000;
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           numbers[i] = randomNum();
      }
 }

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      out.println(
             "Based upon extensive research of "
              + "astro-illogical trends, psychic farces, "
              + "and detailed statistical claptrap, "
              + "we have chosen the " + numbers.length
              + " best lottery numbers for you."
              );
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           out.println(numbers[i]);
      }

 }

 @Override
 public long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest request) {
      return (modTime);
 }


 private int randomNum() {
      return ((int) (Math.random() * 100));
 }
}
```

Comment: When the client app (like a browser) makes request to your servlet with "If-Modified-Since" request-header field, "HttpServlet.getLastModified" is called to check if the requested content has not been modified since the given time.When "not modified" ,the response will be returned 304 without any contents.It is possible to avoid the inefficient communication by keeping the cache in a client side or servlet-filter for cache.RFC2616 for more information.